# Compress (squeeze) strings in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, compression, qr-code

I'm writing a JavaScript app which generates QR codes and displays them. Now as QR codes aren't meant for long string, I would like to compress my data so the result would be shorter in character count wise.

I've done some research but what I've found is not good fore my case.

Most compression algorithms produce some gibberish with unknown symbols with output bigger than input, others generate bytes which are actually bigger than intial string (eg. "test" becomes "85 0b ce 30 00 c4").

I'm not familiar with encryption, compression and encoding, but I was under impression there would be some solution which would actually produce a string with slightly less characters based on input. Is there any?

Comment: Compression that outputs a larger value than input is not compression. That’s encryption

Comment: Per https://www.qrcode.com/en/about/, "up to 7,089 characters can be encoded in one symbol", although at this level, the error correction encoding will be minimal...  Bear in mind too that if you compress the string and render it as a QR code, that only your software will be able to interpret the QR code in its uncompressed form.  Ie, any other software that reads the QR code will only be able to return the compressed string...